# FIltering a PWM signal?

Tags: pwm

[image]
The first box is my modulating signal and the last box is my demodulated signal (filtered signal)

I used my signal to change the duty Cycle of a PWM modulator (fix PWM frequency and variable Duty cycle ).
MY PWM **output frequency** is 20KHz.
My **input signal** it will be from 0 to 100Hz.

My question is what is the best way to filter the signal to obtain the lowest distortion ?

I have two way, the simple one is to use an diode envelop detector:
[image]

The second which I just read about is Infinite Impedance Detector
[image]

What are your recommendations ? 
Is it enough to use an diode envelop detector with third order low pass filer to eliminate the ripples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of a solution that is inappropriate. Filtering a PWM signal requires only low pass filtering and not envelope detection and certainly not the 2nd circuit you have shown.

For simple filters use a resistor and capacitor in series across the PWM output to ground. The capacitor is grounded and the common R and C node voltage has the filtered output. A more sophisticated filter might be based around an op-amp 2nd order filter and this is akin to replacing the resistor with an inductor.

Higher order filters give improved results i.e. smaller ripple voltages due to the unmodulated PWM frequency.

If your modulation frequency is 100Hz try making an RC lowpass filter with a 3dB cut-off at about 200Hz. There will be some attenuation of 100Hz signals (maybe 1dB) and if this is too much progress to an op-amp (or inductor) 2nd order filter.

Comment: How could I calculated the ripple amplitude of the output of a 3rd order Sallen-Key Butterworth Low-pass filter with 200Hz cutoff frequency , 12V 25KHz Modulated signal & 2.5V 100Hz modulating signal

Comment: A 3rd order low pass filter's output falls away at 60dB per decade above the cut off. This means for a 200Hz cut-off a 20kHz signal will be 120dB down in amplitude.